# 2 column index vs 3 column index performance-wise

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

**Background:**

Let's say I have a table named **mytable** with the following columns:

1. ID (unique)
2. user_id (string)
3. creation_date (date)
4. deleted (boolean)
5. ... (more unimportant columns)

and my query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE user_id = 'abcdefg1234567'
AND creation_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 10:00:00' AND '2019-01-01 10:00:00';
```

**My question:**

Is there a performance difference between these 2 indexes (when executing my specific query):

1. (user_id, creation_date)
2. (user_id, creation_date, deleted)

I hope there's no information missing in order to answer this question.

Thank you very much!

Comment: *I have a table named mytable with the following columns* Replace with CREATE TABLE (unnesessary fields may be skipped, but indices and table options must be shown). *1. ID (unique)* Really NOT primary? *Is there a performance difference between these 2 indexes* If indices are used (separately, of course) - 90% that the difference cannot be measured (is less than measurement accuracy), and 10% that it is absent at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query filters on columns `user_id` and `creation_date`. It would of course benefit an index on `(user_id, creation_date)` (option 1 in your question).

MySQL would *also* be able to take a advantage of an index on `(user_id, creation_date, deleted)`, because the columns that the query needs are in first position in the index definition; if it was `(deleted, user_id, creation_date)`, the query would not take advantage of it.

So I would not expect a notable performance difference between the two set-ups, the existing index should be used in both cases; you can confirm that by generating the `explain` plan of each statement.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure GMB's answer is clear.  Either index would be used on the query.  You should not see any performance difference between them.  (There might actually be a tad bit more overhead to the second index because it is physically larger.)

MySQL actually has good [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on multi-column indexes, which explain how they get used.

There is no reason to have both indexes.  You can simply have the second and it will cover the `where` clause of your query.